# Dynamic query is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I am getting the row number from user by clicking on the row. Then i am storing that number (got by user) in an integer. They i am applying dynamic query to fetch relevant data from database. But it not working my query is following
"select Title from project1 where ID = x" 
Where ID and titlw is the name of my columns and project1 is the name of table.

Here is my C# Code

```
private void letsee()
{
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title from project1 where ID = x", conn))
        {
            // create a SQL parameter to add them to the command - this will limit the results to the single user
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("Title", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
            p.Value = 1;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

            // as we are only selecting one column and one row we can use ExecuteScalar
            string connType = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();

           //to display on the frontend
            NEW.InnerText = connType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is ID an integer or String?  A parameter must have '@'.  So you should have "select @Title...." and SqlParameter("@Title"....

Comment: ExecuteReader.ToString() is not what you think it is.

Comment: Is this really MySQL? Because if so you are using the wrong provider (`SqlCommand`, `SqlParameter`). You need to use `MySqlCommand`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't put you id properly in the query.

Correct version would look like that (note @ sign):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Title from project1 where ID = @Id", conn);
```

Then

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Id";
param.Value         = 1;
```

Finally

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Refere [here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06) for tutorial.

Comment: Still its not working. Its not working. It is throwing error as "Invalid column name 'x'."   While  x is just an integer which i am getting from user. Then on the base of x i wanna show relevant title. But its not working.

Comment: Where do you have "x" in your code? Could you share a snippet?